# File corruption on samba share

Tags: filesystems, smb, shared-folders

I have a Samba 2.0 share, setup with a Western Digital WDTVLIVE device.

I'm playing mp3 files from this share (from MacOS Music, Windows MusicBee and iOS Evermusic apps).

What happened some days ago is that there exist corrupted files on the share, essentially files become folders and it is not possible to rename or restore them anymore.

For example //Mp3/Metallica/One.mp3 file become //Mp3/Metallica/One.mp3 empty folder.

I really don't know the reason for this, I'm not able to correlate this corruption to client apps.

Is maybe some issue with SMB 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://community.wd.com/t/wdtv-live-random-avi-files-being-converted-to-folders/35209/123. It's needed to downgrade firmware since it seems depending on latest version.